# How to retrieve data from mysql to a datagridview that contains an image column?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I tried retrieving data from MySQL to datagridview. The table contains an image column. When I remove the image column, the code works fine but it doesn't seem to work with the image column included.

Here's my code.

```
Mda= new mysldataadapter ("select * from user_info", con)
Dt = new datatable
Mda.fill(dt)

With datagridview1
. Datasource =dt
End with
```

I get this error msg

> Datagridview default error dialog
>   System.argumentexception: parameter is not valid at
>   system.drawing.image.fromstream(....

Comment: What is the data type of your column in your database.  What is the data type of the `DataColumn` in your `DataTable`?  How EXACTLY was the data obtained and saved in the first place?

Comment: I used longblob data type to save the image

Comment: I obtained the data straight from mysql workbench and saved it in the image column

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "straight from MySQL workbench".  That seems to suggest that you got it from another database.  Did you?  Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation.  Assume too many words are better than not enough.  If the data did come from a different database, how did it get there?  How do you know that it represents a valid `Image` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MemoryStream` to store the image then show it... something like this :

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `id`, `pic` FROM `mytb` WHERE `id` = @ID", connection)

command.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.UInt64).Value = TextBoxID.Text

Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
Dim DBTable As New DataTable()

Try
    Adapter.Fill(DBTable)

    Dim imgByte() As Byte

    If DBTable.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        imgByte = DBTable(0)(1)

        Dim MS As New MemoryStream(imgByte)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MS)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
End Try
```

**NOTE :** The data type for the column must be `BLOB`.

Feel free to ask about anything you don't understand.

**Hope that was helpful.**